# Not able to start ISC BIND service in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bind, internal-dns, 32-bit

I have windows 7 32-bit machine. I have installed BIND 9.2 as per the instructions in the link http://www.misterfahrenheit.com/2011/09/04/how-to-setup-a-dns-server-with-bind-on-windows-7-part-2/.

When i start the **ISC BIND** service its giving me the error as below.

[image]

I followed many articles to do that, But i am not able to get it exactly.

**I have given the service account credentials with the my windows 7 account (type:administrator) during installation**

**Is that windows 7 supports BIND installation**

Can anyone post me the exact reference to install and configure it on windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Odds are that you've got a mistake in your configuration file causing bind to terminate. Running it from the command line to test, rather than as a service, will probably give you some insight into the problems.